# Type error in Python 2.7 for some simple recursive code

Tags: python, recursion, types

I'm having a type error with some recursive code in Python 2.7.  The code below is essentially a riemann integral, where you add up the area of rectangles underneath a curve.  It works perfectly when 'step' is 0.25 or greater, but the type error occurs when it is less than 0.25.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

The following error occurs for the last line of code:

```
  File "/home/i/PycharmProjects/6.00.1x/prob3/radiationExposure.py", line 25, in radiationExposure
return f(stop - step) * step + radiationExposure(start, (stop - step), step)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

My code is as follows:

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):

'''
    Computes and returns the amount of radiation exposed
    to between the start and stop times. Calls the
    function f to obtain the value of the function at any point.

    start: integer, the time at which exposure begins
    stop: integer, the time at which exposure ends
    step: float, the width of each rectangle. You can assume that
      the step size will always partition the space evenly.

    returns: float, the amount of radiation exposed to
      between start and stop times.
    '''

    if stop - step == start:
        return f(stop - step) * step
    elif stop - step > start:
        return f(stop - step) * step + radiationExposure(start, (stop - step), step)
```

Note to those with ethics: This is to satisfy my own curiosity. There is no grade for the archived MIT course on edx.org, and recursive code isn't required for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The function `radiationExposure` given in your question returns `None` when `stop-step < start` because neither of the `if` conditions is met.

```
if stop - step == start:
    return f(stop - step) * step
elif stop - step > start:
    return f(stop - step) * step + radiationExposure(start, (stop - step), step)
# If the execution reaches this point and the function ends, it will return None
```

If you are expecting arithmetic to give you exactly `stop-step==start`, then don't use floating point variables, because they are approximations.

If you instead had:

```
if stop - step <= start:
    return f(stop - step) * step
else:
    return f(stop - step) * step + radiationExposure(start, stop - step, step)
```

that would at least ensure that the function returned a number instead of `None`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you for taking the time to help me, khelwood.